# Python SQLITE- Close Database connection takes too long for Big Database after inserting few rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite database of size 10 GB . I run a script daily to insert few rows of data. When I close the connection to database it takes around 10 minutes and keeps on eating  my space in C drive until connection closes automatically. wondering what to do when it becomes 20 GB. I don't have 20 Gb free space in C drive

Sample python code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()

Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

conn.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the standard recommendation is going to be "use a real database engine". If that's not an option, any possibility of splitting the data over multiple files (e.g. archiving less-used data)?

Comment: if you don't have 20 gb of space well, then you probably can't have a 20 gb database...

Comment: I have  the database in shared Drive. So space isn’t a issue. It only eats up space in C drive while closing connection.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour occurs when the database is in [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), and when your program does something to prevent the database from doing automatic [checkpoints](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt).

Either use a different [journal mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), or fix the [wal_autocheckpoint setting](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_autocheckpoint), or fix your program so that it does not leak active transactions/cursors.

Comment: I have come up with interesting observations. When the 10GB database file is in c drive it takes only a second to close the connection but when on network drive it takes 10 minutes to close the connection and eats my C drive space ( exactly the same problem explained above)

Any thoughts guys?